# Which audio codec G.722 or G.726 offer improved stability and lower delays?

Tags: algorithm, audio, compression, signal-processing

I have to choose between **G.722** and **G.726** audio codecs.

Assume, that:

- purpose to use audio codec is VoIP over SIP calls
- and we do not consider bandwidth of Internet connection (it's high)

I need **high audio quality**, **lower delays** and **higher stability**.

Which one of them provides it better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_codecs#Technical_details):

***Audio quality:***

- **722**: 16 kHz, 64 kb/s, 14 bits/sample
- **726**: 8 kHz, <=40 kb/s, 13 bits/sample

***Latency:***

- **722**: 4000 us
- **726**: 125 us

So it depends on what you want more. 722 clearly has the better quality, but at a higher latency. The latency isn't all that bad, though, compared to other formats. Also note that 722 uses sub-band encoding, which could be handy for a VOIP application. If you're encoding it yourself, you can tweak the typical "voice" band to use more bits than others, and possibly reduce the file size.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "stability". Normally for VOIP I'd say use a low-bandwidth codec to provide stability, but you specifically state that's not an issue.